# How do I convert from void * back to int in C

Tags: c

if I have

```
int a= 5;
long b= 10;
int count0 = 2;
void ** args0;
args0 = (void **)malloc(count0 * sizeof(void *));
args0[0] = (void *)&a;
args0[1] = (void *)&b;
```

how can I convert from args[0] and args0[1] back to int and long?
for example

```
int c=(something im missing)args0[0]
long d=(something im missing)args1[0]
```

Comment: Just as a side remark, I think it is no good practice to cast `void*` to `int` or `long`. The width of integers and of pointers need not necessarily be the same on a given platform. A more portable way is to use `intptr_t` or even better `uintptr_t`. This guarantees that you don't loose bits.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that your &a0 and &b0 are supposed to be &a and &b, and that you mean args0[1] for setting up long d, you have stored a pointer to a in args0[0] and a pointer to b in args0[1]. This means you need to convert them to the correct pointer types.

```
int c = *((int *)args0[0]);
int d = *((long *)args0[1]);
```

Answer (score 5):

To literally answer your question, you'd write

```
int c = *((int *)args0[0]);
long d = *((long *)args[1]);
```

What might concern me about your code is that you have allocated space for the *pointers* to your locations, but you haven't allocated memory for the *values* themselves. If you expect to persist these locations beyond the local scope, you have to do something like:

```
int *al = malloc(sizeof(int));
long *bl = malloc(sizeof(long));
*al = a;
*bl = b;
void **args0 = malloc(2 * sizeof(void *));
args0[0] = al;
args0[1] = bl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 int c =  *( (int *)  args0[0]);

 long d = *( (long *) args0[1]);
```

Comment: int c=*((int )args0[0]);
causes error: invalid type argument of 'unary *' (have 'int')
and 
int c=((int *)args0[0]);
fprintf(stderr,"main(): %d \n",c);
causes the output to be -4261808

Comment: I don't get it. What is the difference between my answer and the one on the top (which is accepted)?

Comment: When you first posted, the "*" was missing after 'int' for some reason, perhaps due to it being interpreted as formatting -- see w31's comment for how it looked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it that the void* should be interpreted as an int* or long* when you dereference.

```
int a = 5;
long b = 10;
void *args[2];
args[0] = &a;
args[1] = &b;

int c = *(int*)args[0];
long d = *(long*)args[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

While others have answered your question, I will make a comment about the last three lines in the first part of your code snippet:

```
args0 = (void **)malloc(count0 * sizeof(void *));
args0[0] = (void *)&a;
args0[1] = (void *)&b;
```

The above is better written as:

```
args0 = malloc(count0 * sizeof *args0);
args0[0] = &a;
args0[1] = &b;
```

The `malloc()` call is easier to read this way, and less error-prone.  You don't need a cast in the last two statements since C guarantees conversions to and from an object pointer and a void pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing, i suggest use it an external function, to get more readability:

```
int get_int(void* value){
    return *((int*) value);
}

long get_long(void* value){
    return *((long*) value);
}
```

then in your code:

```
 int c =  get_int(args0[0]);

 long d = get_long(args0[1]);
```

That should work.