# Segmentation fault on typecasting void pointer to int

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, void, void-pointers

Seeing this thread I wrote the following: [How do I convert from void * back to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200294/how-do-i-convert-from-void-back-to-int)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void* port = (void*) atoi (argv[1]);

    cout << "\nvalue: \n" << atoi (argv[1]) << "\n";

    int h = *((int *)port);
    cout << h;
}
```

output:

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/> ./a.out 323

value: 
323
Segmentation fault
anisha@linux-dopx:~/>
```

GCC

What's the point that I am missing?

Comment: I don't think casting from int to void* is intentional at all. That alone causes the seg fault when you try to dereference void* due to unallocated memeory at location 323.

Comment: @ksming which line to change?

Comment: The difference with the question that you link to is that there a cast from int* is done to void*, so there you should cast back to int*.  You do a cast from int to void* so in this case you should cast back to int.  However, try avoid this casting.

Comment: See my comment on Luchian's answer to avoid the casting altogether if you need this for creating threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, please ignore my previous answer. Instead of `(char*)port - (char*)0`, please do the following:

```
int h = *(int *)(&port);
```

You're getting the address of `port`:

```
&port
```

Casting the address to an `int *`:

```
(int *)(&port)
```

Then dereferencing the address to get back the integer value you put into `port`:

```
*(int *)(&port)
```

Comment: this works. :) Thanks. In my original post I didn't know what I was doing! Swift answers on SO have spoiled me. :D

Comment: No worries. This was educational for me, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring potential issues with the intermediate conversions, you start with an `int` and end up treating it as if it were `int*`. In other words, you treat the result of `atoi()` as an *address*, and try to read the memory at that address.

Comment: But this `void* port = atoi (argv[1]);` results in `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’
`

Answer (score 1):

I made the following adjustment, based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8075684/19410):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *port = (void *) atoi(argv[1]);

    cout << "\nvalue: \n" << atoi (argv[1]) << "\n";

    int h = (char*)port - (char*)0;    
    cout << h;
}
```

Result:

```
$ g++ -Wall test.cpp
$ ./a.out 323

value: 
323
323
```

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks. could you explain it? `(char*)port - (char*)0;`

Comment: This seems like undefined behavior to me: arithmetic with a pointer that points nowhere and a null-pointer that doesn't necessary points to address 0x00000000... I can see how it should work with most common compilers.

Comment: My thoughts on this may be wrong, but I'll throw this out there for others to comment on. The subtraction operator can take two pointers of the same type. Subtracting the address of '0' from the address of a `char *` of `port` (here, really an `int`) returns the number of 1-byte `char` elements between them, the number being implicitly cast back to an `int`. (Try replacing `char *` with `int *` and your answer `h` should be divided by `sizeof(int)`, often four bytes.)

Comment: Please ignore this answer and see my other one. I think my newer answer makes more sense and is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You try to typecast `port` to an int pointer, but it is not a pointer. It is a value. You are using `323` as a pointer. If you want to get an `int *` then either typecast `argv[1]` or a pointer to `port`. Port should also probably not be declared as a `void *` as it is processed to an int in `atoi()`, it should probably be simply an `int`.

Comment: I "need to" declare port as void *. I want to get an int as a answer. whic line to correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're dereferencing a pointer which points to memory you don't own, which is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @AnishaKaul it's not a specific line, it's the logic that's faulty. `void* port = (void*) atoi (argv[1]);` this gives you a pointer to memory you don't own, which you're trying to de-reference.

Comment: actually, the port needs to be passed as a void pointer to a function "pthread_create". That's why I typecasted it.

Comment: @anisha: there are discussions about this, but I think passing to pthread_create should be done by dynamic memory: int\* pArg = new int; \*pArg = atoi(...); pthread_create(...pArg...); and delete the argument inside the new thread.  It is not the most C++-like, but it respects the void* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Change below line

```
void* port = (void*) atoi (argv[1]);
```

to

```
int port = atoi (argv[1]);
```

Comment: that results in `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’
`

Comment: this is c++ - strict typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

use this

int h = ((int )port);

Because you converted **int** to **void***

Now convert back **void*** to **int** by `((int )port)`

So use `int h = ((int )port);`