# Invalid use of void expression with threads (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, syntax-error, void-pointers

I've looked through tons of answers on here that skirt around my issue, but none answer the problem I am facing.

I am coding a multi-threaded program in C that does matrix multiplication to evaluate system performance.

Currently I am simply trying to start a single thread while passing in a couple variables.

This is my code

```
pthread_t *thread = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

int a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int b = malloc(sizeof(int));
a = 0;
b = size;
void **args = (void **) malloc(2 * sizeof(void *));
args[0] = (void *)a;
args[1] = (void *)b;

pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, matrixMath, &args);
```

And the matrixMath method:

```
void* matrixMath(void* args) {
  int start = *((int *)args[0]);
  int end = *((int *)args[1]);

  printf("Start: %d, End: %d\n", start, end);

  return NULL;
}
```

Whenever I try to compile, I get an "invalid use of void expression" at both the "int start" and "int end" declarations. I based those lines on [the discussion found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200294/how-do-i-convert-from-void-back-to-int?newreg=aedb47c59b5d4a71945d5053d253a8e0). Any help?

Comment: Why do you set `a` and `b` to values return by `malloc` and then set them to something else, leaking the memory you allocated?

Answer (score 2):

Since `args` is a `void *`, you can't dereference it, but `args[0]` does attempt to dereference it before the `(int *)` cast is applied.  So, you need to reparenthesize so the `void *` is converted to an `int *` before you dereference it:

```
int start = ((int *)args)[0];
int end   = ((int *)args)[1];
```

Alternatively (but equivalently):

```
int *array = (int *)args;  // You could skip the cast in C
int start  = args[0];
int end    = args[1];
```

I'm not convinced about `&args` in the call to `pthread_create()` either.  That passes a `void ***` to the thread code.  I think you need something more like this, which has multiple merits including being simpler:

```
pthread_t thread;
int *a = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = size;

pthread_create(&thread, NULL, matrixMath, a);
```

You could even use:

```
pthread_t thread;
int a[] = { 0, size };
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, matrixMath, a);
```

Comment: I very much like the simplicity of the code, this really is the way to think of it. But since it seems difficult to understand, the part inside the thread function should perhaps also be elaborated. Something like `int* bound = args` and then accessing `bound[0]`.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. I didn't realize that the parentheses were breaking the dereferencing. Also, I actually did have something closer to your second block originally, but I was trying things to make it work based on that previous question I posted. Thanks for clarifying that bit though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to demonstrate an alternative approach, using a `struct`. This alternative approach is easier to both code and maintain over time.

Your code has a few issues that might cause compiler and runtime errors, here are a few examples that should point you to the right path:

1. Your `int` assignment isn't performing what you might have wanted or intended it to perform.

   Your code assigns the numerical value of a pointer's address to an integer, probably truncating the data due to variable size differences... What you probably wanted was to store a pointer to an int.

   You wrote:

   ```
   int a = malloc(sizeof(int));
   int b = malloc(sizeof(int));
   ```

   You probably meant to write:

   ```
   int * a = malloc(sizeof(int));
   int * b = malloc(sizeof(int));
   ```
2. Your code is treating `void *` as a `void **` (or `int *`) without using any casting...

   You wrote:

   ```
   int start = *((int *)args[0]);
   int end   = ((int *)args)[1];
   ```

   You probably meant to write:

   ```
   int start = ( (int *)args )[0];
   int end   = ( (int *)args )[1];
   ```
3. Your code performs `malloc` three (3) times, but never calls `free` (you have a memory leak).

It would be easier if you defined a `struct` to contain the data you wanted to "move" to (or share with) the thread.

For example, the following ***untested*** code probably doesn't work, but it clearly show the concept of how using a `struct` makes data transfer easier to manage, maintain and update. It also requires less calls to `malloc`, making memory management easier.

```
struct ThreadData {
   int start;
   int end;
};

void * thread_task(void *);

int main(void) {
   struct ThreadData * data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
   data->start = 0;
   data->end = 0; // = size;
   pthread_t thr;
   pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thread_task, data);
   // ... do whatever.
   // ... remember to join thread
}

void * thread_task(void * _data) {
   struct ThreadData * data = _data;
   printf("Start: %d, End: %d\n", data->start, data->end);
   // remember to free the memory when you're done.
   free(data);
   return NULL;
}
```

This approach is much easier to both code and maintain. Also, when you need to add data for the new thread, it's easy - just update the struct.

You can even put complex return values back into place-holders in the struct, allowing the thread to perform more complex tasks (remember to avoid having more than a single thread writing to the same `struct` field).